# Two variables inside a TryParse loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, tryparse

I am new at programming and I am trying to create a loop where the while condition is based on variables however I don't know the correct syntax for it.
That's what I am trying to do, even though it may not be allowed...I think.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float totalArea, areaUnbuilt;

            while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalArea, out areaUnbuilt)) 
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert total area in square meters:");
                float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalArea);
                Console.WriteLine("Insira are not built in square meters:");
                float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out areaUnbuilt);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get from the compiler? What line do they indicate is your problem?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use two out variables in a TryParse. Moreover, how do you think to separate the two values from the command line?

Comment: it only works like this:  while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalArea) && (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out areaUnbuilt)))

Answer (score 0):

You can't use TryParse to get back two out values. Instead change your code to a do..while loop

```
bool isArea = true;
bool isUnbuilt = true;
do
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Insert total area in square meters:");
    isArea = float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalArea);
    Console.WriteLine("Insert area not built in square meters:");
    isUnbuilt = float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out areaUnbuilt);
} while( !isArea || !isUnbuilt);
```